# Page_Load() load data don't go away

Tags: c#

I am working on a visual web part that does simple CRUD operations and I have this strange behavior in Page_load().
I grab first record from query and assign some text fields when page is loaded. When I clear the form and update the form with new different inputs, those text fields remember the first values and ignores newly entered data.
Am I missing anything in Page_load() when I display data when the page is loaded?

```html
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        string connstr = AdminDashBoard.Utility.GetConnectionString();
        private DataSet sqlDst = new DataSet();
        private static int RowNo = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
          
            string strQuery = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
         
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                sqlAdap.Fill(sqlDst);

                //these fields remember first assigned data!!!
                this.TextBox1.Text = sqlDst.Tables[0].Rows[RowNo][0].ToString();
                this.TextBox2.Text = sqlDst.Tables[0].Rows[RowNo][1].ToString();
                this.TextBox3.Text = sqlDst.Tables[0].Rows[RowNo][2].ToString();
                this.DateTimeControl1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDst.Tables[0].Rows[RowNo][3].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();                
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to populate the controls from the database on postback. Try making the first statement in Page_Load `if(Page.IsPostBack) return;`

Comment: They don't "remember" data, _you_ are setting them on each `Page_Load` exactly has you have written your code. See above comment on determining the difference between an _initial request_  (`GET`) from a `POST`back and handle each accordingly. Also likely a good time to review [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) Hth.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. BTW, I don't see a 'check' thing (like a v) next to the answers. I want to accept as an answer.